# How to apply Comodo SSL to Kubernetes Ingress?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

We purchased a Komodo SSL certificate, which come in 5 files:

[image]

I am looking for a guide for how to apply it on our Kubernetes Ingress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it described in [documentation:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls)

you need to create secret with your cert:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: content_of_file_condohub_com_br.crt
  tls.key: content_of_file_HSSL-5beedef526b9e.key
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-tls
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
```

and then update your ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tls-example-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - your.amazing.host.com
    secretName: secret-tls
  rules:
    - host: your.amazing.host.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: service1
            servicePort: 80
```

Ingress will use the certs from secret files.