# Kubernetes SSL from Purchased Wildcard SSL

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I am trying to implement wildcard SSL for my domain with Kubernetes.  I could not find any example of how to do that with purchased Wildcard Certificate (comodo).  All examples are those using LetsEncrypt Acme.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a secret:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: testsecret-tls
  namespace: default
data:
  tls.crt: base64 encoded cert 
  tls.key: base64 encoded key
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

Once you done that only thing to do is to Refere this secret in an Ingress tells the Ingress controller to secure the channel from the client to the load balancer using TLS:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tls-example-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - https-example.foo.com
    secretName: testsecret-tls
  rules:
  - host: https-example.foo.com
...
```

For more reading please visit Kubernete documents at [/Services-and-Netowrking/Ingress-tls](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls)

Comment: is the tls.crt and tls.key from my wildcard ssl ?

Comment: Please have a look at this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378005/how-to-apply-comodo-ssl-to-kubernetes-ingress). It an example with comodo certs.